# Why transition metal catalyzed [2+2]cycloaddition reactions allowed?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

As you know, cycloaddition reactions which (4n)π electrons are involved in such as [2+2]cycloaddition are forbidden in normal organic reactions, but transition metal catalyzed [2+2]cycloaddition reactions are allowed.
I think the d orbitals of transition metals play important roles in the reactions, but I cannot understand how they work.

I found this article on the Internet, and the reaction is explained.

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00734a016#

Comment: When metals are involved, the typical rules for thermal/photochemical [2+2] reactions don’t really apply. The metal generally involves a non-concerted (I.e. stepwise) process, so no issue with it